# Shortcode to insert menu in page body?

Tags: functions, shortcode

I need to insert a menu in the text of one page. I found these two plugin but none of them work. Both of them haven't been updated for 6 years:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-menu/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-menu-shortcode/

I found this code to create my own shortcode

```
    function print_menu_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'name' => null, 'class' => null ), $atts));
return wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $name, 'menu_class' => $class, 'echo' => false ) );
}

add_shortcode('menu', 'print_menu_shortcode');
```

And then shortcode should be:

```
[menu name="-your menu name-" class="-your class-"]
```

It works but the class is not printed at all. **What is wrong in the function?** I need to print the class.

Comment: No, WordPress doesn't do that by itself. Yes, you can create a function to do that.

Comment: I just edited my question to insert a code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That code should work.  Are you usign "myclass" as the class and not ".myclass"?

Is this for a specific use where class will always be the same?  If you're only looking to ever use this on one place, you can do this:

```
    function print_menu_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'name' => null, 'class' => null ), $atts));
return wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $name, 'menu_class' => 'myclass', 'echo' => false ) );
}

add_shortcode('menu', 'print_menu_shortcode');
```

Then change the section 'menu_class' => 'myclass' with the class you need.  this will avoid having to use the class.  Again, don't use the "." in front of the class here.

Short code usage:

```
[menu name="menu_name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this years too late, but just in case anybody encounters this again, you can use this code to be able include a class with your shortcode and its return value. I modified it with the corresponding answers before in here.

```
function print_menu_shortcode($atts=[], $content = null) {
    $shortcode_atts = shortcode_atts([ 'name' => '', 'class' => '' ], $atts);
    $name   = $shortcode_atts['name'];
    $class  = $shortcode_atts['class'];
    return wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $name, 'menu_class' => $class, 'echo' => false ) );
}
```

Shortcode:
`[menu name="menu_name" class="your_class"]`

I hope this helps anyone that may need it in the future!